# Hyperlinks are disabled when using ui-sref in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My HTML hyperlinks are removed/disabled when I make use of the UIRouter state routing. The code I implemented looks like this:

```
// app.route.js
$stateProvider
    .state('weather_details', {
      url:'/weather/:woeid',
      component:'weather_details'
    });

// weather_detail.component.js
function WeatherDetailsController($log, $rootScope, $translate, $stateParams) {
    const vmwd = this;
    vmwd.stateParams = {};
    vmwd.stateParams.keyword = $stateParams.keyword;
    ...
}
```

I have a hyperlink of the form:

```
// weather.view.html
<a ui-sref="weather({keyword: vmw.weather.woeid})">
Link
</a>
```

Why are my links disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the reason was I specified the url in the state as:

```
url:'/weather/:woeid'
```

And I specified in the s-ref:

```
<a ui-sref="weather({keyword: vmw.weather.keyword})">
```

The link should be:

```
<a ui-sref="weather({keyword: vmw.weather.woeid})">
```